# make div visible when another div is activated by a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make 1 button show two divs when I click it using jquery.

So on click of button #show1 I want div #cybernetics + div .gif1 to appear and on click on button #show2 I want div #eat + div .gif2 to appear

Is it possible? thank you!
currently I have the following code

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show1, #show2, #show3').click( function() {
        var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
        $('.demo').not($div).hide();
        $div.fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show1" data-href="cybernetics"><h2> ></h2></button>
<button id="show2" data-href="eat"><h2> ></h2></button>

<div id="cybernetics" class="demo">
      <header>
        <h1>CYBERNETICS</h1>
      </header>
    </div>

<div class="gif1">
     <img src="cybernetics.gif">
</div>

 <div id="eat" class="demo">
       <header>
        <h1>E.A.T.</h1>
      </header>
</div>

<div class="gif2">
     <img src="eat.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: You already have the logic to show/hide elements, what's the issue?

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Please read "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)"

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can show hide as per button click as bewlo.

```js
   

 
   $('.gif1, .gif2, #cybernetics, #eat').hide();
$('document').ready(function() {
  
    
    
    $('#show1').click( function() {
    
       $('.gif1, .gif2, #cybernetics, #eat').hide();
       $('#cybernetics').show();
       $('.gif1').show();
    });
    
    $('#show2').click( function() {
       $('.gif1, .gif2, #cybernetics, #eat').hide();
       $('#eat').show();
       $('.gif2').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show1" data-href="cybernetics"><h2> ></h2></button>
<button id="show2" data-href="eat"><h2> ></h2></button>

<div id="cybernetics" class="demo">
      <header>
        <h1>CYBERNETICS</h1>
      </header>
    </div>

<div class="gif1">
     <img src="cybernetics.gif">
</div>

 <div id="eat" class="demo">
       <header>
        <h1>E.A.T.</h1>
      </header>
</div>

<div class="gif2">
     <img src="eat.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the logic you're trying to keep this DRY, so you don't want multiple event handlers. As such you can select the target element based on the `data-href` attribute of the clicked button, then get the `next()` element from that and fade them both in, something like this:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
    $('.demo').not($div).hide().next().hide();
    $div.add($div.next()).fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.demo, 
.demo + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show1" class="toggle" data-href="cybernetics"><h2> ></h2></button>
<button id="show2" class="toggle" data-href="eat"><h2> ></h2></button>

<div id="cybernetics" class="demo">
  <header>
    <h1>CYBERNETICS</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="gif1">
  <img src="cybernetics.gif">
</div>

<div id="eat" class="demo">
  <header>
    <h1>E.A.T.</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="gif2">
  <img src="eat.gif">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make change to below code

```
<button id="show1" data-href="cybernetics"><h2> ></h2></button>
<button id="show2" data-href="eat"><h2> ></h2></button>

<div class="allBox cybernetics" style="display: none;">
  <header>
    <h1>CYBERNETICS</h1>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="allBox cybernetics" style="display: none;">
  <img src="cybernetics.gif">
</div>

<div class="allBox eat" style="display: none;">
  <header>
    <h1>E.A.T.</h1>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="allBox eat" style="display: none;">
  <img src="eat.gif">
</div>
```

and your js code goes here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#show1").on('click', function(){
    hrefVal = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(".allBox").css('display', 'none');
    $("."+hrefVal).css('display', 'block');
})
$("#show2").on('click', function(){
    hrefVal = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(".allBox").css('display', 'none');
    $("."+hrefVal).css('display', 'block');
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution maintaining your data structure and name convention. 
I also fix a bug when clicking multiple times on the same button would fade in and out the right items.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show1, #show2, #show3').click( function() {
        var target = $(this).data('href');
        var $div = $('#' + target);
        $('.demo').not($div).hide();
        $(".gif img:not([src^='"+target+"'])").hide();
        $(".gif img[src^='"+target+"']").show();
        $div.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show1" data-href="cybernetics"><h2> ></h2></button>
<button id="show2" data-href="eat"><h2> ></h2></button>

<div id="cybernetics" class="demo">
      <header>
        <h1>CYBERNETICS</h1>
      </header>
    </div>

<div class="gif">
     <img src="cybernetics.gif">
</div>

 <div id="eat" class="demo">
       <header>
        <h1>E.A.T.</h1>
      </header>
</div>

<div class="gif">
     <img src="eat.gif">
</div>
```